# Как сравнить первые две цифры четырехзначного числа и последние две цифры четырехзначного числа?

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        private void Load_B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TPeople[] peoples = new TPeople[0];
        int n = 0;
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open("data.dat", FileMode.Open)))
        {
            while (br.PeekChar() != -1)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref peoples, ++n);

                peoples[n - 1].LastName = br.ReadString();
                peoples[n - 1].NumTeleph = br.ReadInt32();
                peoples[n - 1].YearTeleph = br.ReadInt32();
            }
        }

        PeoplesLoad_DGV.RowCount = n;

        int min_index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                if (min_index == -1)
                    min_index = i;
                else
                    if (peoples[i].YearTeleph == peoples[min_index].NumTeleph)
                        min_index = i;
        if (min_index != -1)
        {
            PeoplesLoad_DGV[0, 0].Value = peoples[min_index].LastName;
            PeoplesLoad_DGV[1, 0].Value = peoples[min_index].NumTeleph;
            PeoplesLoad_DGV[2, 0].Value = peoples[min_index].YearTeleph;
        }
        else
        {
            PeoplesLoad_DGV[0, 0].Value = "Не Найдено";
            PeoplesLoad_DGV[1, 0].Value = "";
            PeoplesLoad_DGV[2, 0].Value = "";
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, приведите конкретные  примеры. И причем тут метка winforms?

Comment: ну допустим есть число 1234. И второе число 4312. Получается проверка должна быть следующая: 12 == 12.

Comment: Первые две цифры должны сравниваться с последними двумя? В каком формате представлены эти числа? Гарантируется ли, что они четырехзначные? Приведите в вопрос несколько примеров  ожидаемого поведения кода, желательно со своей попыткой решить задачу.

Comment: `1234 / 100 == 4312 % 100`

Comment: "проверка должна быть следующая: 12 == 12." - это не соответствует тексту в вопросе.

Comment: Использовать `var one = Convert.ToString(1234);` потом: `one = one.Substring(2);` и `var two = Convert.ToString(4312); two = two.Substring(two.Length - 2);` и после `if(one == two)`.

Comment: Можно и `"1234".ToString()`, но главное не это - а то, что с цифрами алгоритм более просто расширяем на другую длину цифр. В строках придётся учитывать с какого символа начинать обрезать.

Comment: @AK, для каких целей, строку конвертить в строку?) Жесть. Если прилетит число, каким макаром ваше выражение поможет? Никаким.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В заголовке сказал первые две и последние две, а в примере показал сравнение последних двух цифр у обеих чисел.

```
int a=2235;
int b=3525;
int a1=a/100;//возьмёт целые числа от деления на 100, т.е. первые две цифры
int a2=b%100;//возьмёт остаток от деления на 100, т.е. последние две цифры
```

Пример с массивом класса TPeople[] peoples

```
foreach(TPeople item in peoples)
{

    if(item.NumTeleph%100==item.YearTeleph/100)
         //Код когда окончание номера телефона равно началу года телефона
}
```